# Install repositories from multiple files and recreate yum cache only once

Tags: chef-infra, yum

In one of my Chef cookbooks, I am installing some new repositories from multiple file.

on the [chef documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_execute.html) there is an example of how to rebuild the cache:

```
execute "create-yum-cache" do
 command "yum -q makecache"
 action :nothing
end

ruby_block "reload-internal-yum-cache" do
  block do
    Chef::Provider::Package::Yum::YumCache.instance.reload
  end
  action :nothing
end

cookbook_file "/etc/yum.repos.d/custom.repo" do
  source "custom"
  mode "0644"
  notifies :run, "execute[create-yum-cache]", :immediately
  notifies :create, "ruby_block[reload-internal-yum-cache]", :immediately
end
```

But now let's say I have to update multiple repo files.

```
execute "create-yum-cache" do
 command "yum -q makecache"
 action :nothing
end

ruby_block "reload-internal-yum-cache" do
  block do
    Chef::Provider::Package::Yum::YumCache.instance.reload
  end
  action :nothing
end

cookbook_file "/etc/yum.repos.d/custom.repo" do
  source "custom"
  mode "0644"
  notifies :run, "execute[create-yum-cache]", :immediately
  notifies :create, "ruby_block[reload-internal-yum-cache]", :immediately
end

template '/etc/yum.repos.d/custom2.repo' do
  source 'custom2.repo.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
  notifies :run, 'execute[create-yum-cache]', :immediately
  notifies :create, 'ruby_block[reload-internal-yum-cache]', :immediately
end
```

How do I avoid to reload the cache multiple times?

Comment: Why not use the yum cookbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using this cookbook https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/yum

remember include in metadata.rb

```
depends 'yum'
```

example of how to add two custom repos:

```
yum_repository 'custom' do
  description "my custom Repo"
  baseurl "http://localhost/#{os_release}/#{arch}/stable/"
  gpgkey 'http://localhost/gpg_key'
  action :create
end

yum_repository 'custom2' do
  description "my custom Repo"
  baseurl "http://localhost2/#{os_release}/#{arch}/stable/"
  gpgcheck false
  action :create
end
```

if not use this cookbook here are the providers that refresh yum-cache
https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/yum/blob/master/providers/repository.rb

Sorry for my English!
best regards

Comment: Thanks, I used the idea of reloading the cache per repository even if I didn't use the yum cookbook.